# Using clap's #[derive(Parser)], how can I accept a std::time::Duration?

Tags: rust, clap

I want to accept a `std::time::Duration` on a command line. I'm using `clap` with `#[derive(Parser)]` to generate the parameter parser. Is there any way I can directly accept an input, rather than accepting a number and doing the conversion later?

Something like this:

```
#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
pub struct Config {
    #[clap( ??? )]
    interval: std::time::Duration,
}
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Clap 3.0:

To do custom parsing, you should use `#[clap(parse(try_from_str = ...))]` and define a custom function to parsing the argument. Here's an example:

```
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
pub struct Config {
    #[clap(parse(try_from_str = parse_duration))]
    interval: std::time::Duration,
}

fn parse_duration(arg: &str) -> Result<std::time::Duration, std::num::ParseIntError> {
    let seconds = arg.parse()?;
    Ok(std::time::Duration::from_secs(seconds))
}
```

---

#### Clap 4.0:

Almost same as above; the helper function can stay the same, but the attribute syntax has changed:

```
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
pub struct Config {
    #[arg(value_parser = parse_duration)]
    interval: std::time::Duration,
}

fn parse_duration(arg: &str) -> Result<std::time::Duration, std::num::ParseIntError> {
    let seconds = arg.parse()?;
    Ok(std::time::Duration::from_secs(seconds))
}
```

---

#### Parsing with humantime

This parsing is pretty limited (I don't know what format you'd expect the duration to be in), but it shows how you'd do it.

If you want to be flexible with your duration arguments, consider using a crate like [humantime](https://crates.io/crates/humantime), which lets you provide durations with unit labels like `"5s"` or `"3 hours"`.  You can either use their helper function to parse into a `std::time::Duration` (using clap 4 syntax):

```rust
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
pub struct Config {
    #[clap(value_parser = humantime::parse_duration, default_value = "500ms")]
    interval: std::time::Duration,
}
```

Or you can use [`humantime::Duration`](https://docs.rs/humantime/2.1.0/humantime/struct.Duration.html) without special attributes since it implements `FromStr`.

```rust
use clap::Parser;

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
pub struct Config {
    #[clap(default_value = "500ms")]
    interval: humantime::Duration,
}
```

Comment: I think it might be good to add a code example for how to implement `parse_duration` using `humantime`, like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=6053aacfa34b2cd57f36398a36839eb6

I would have added another answer, but it's too close to yours imo.

Answer (score 5):

Compact version for Clap 4

```rust
use clap::Parser;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::num::ParseIntError;

#[derive(Debug, Parser)]
pub struct Config {
    #[arg(value_parser = |arg: &str| -> Result<Duration, ParseIntError> {Ok(Duration::from_secs(arg.parse()?))})]
    interval_secs: Duration,
}
```

Docs for value_parser:

https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/builder/struct.ValueParser.html#method.new

https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/macro.value_parser.html

Comment: Even more compact: `#[clap(value_parser = |secs: &str| secs.parse().map(Duration::from_secs))]`

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there's a way to differentiate a `u8` or whatever from a `std::time::Duration` on the command line *itself*. That said, you should be able to do something like this if you implement `FromStr` for `Duration`:

```
struct Config {
    #[structopt(short = "i", long = "interval")]
    interval: std::time::Duration,
}
```

But it definitely seems easier to take something like a `u8` and do a conversion in `main()` or similar.

Comment: You cannot implement foreign traits for foreign data structures in Rust.